# what is correct and secure vay to pass url through url

Tags: php

I want to pass url (or even several urls) through url, i.e. use url like `http://domain/file.php?url1=...&url2=...`. The question is how to make such urls safe and working. Will `urlencode()` help.

BTW, if I do `urlencode($url)`, do I need to `urldecode()` before doing `header("Location: $url")`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will urlencode() help.

yes.

> BTW, if I do urlencode($url), do I need to urldecode() before doing
>   header("Location: $url")

no. you'd need to encode the single urls which go to the final url, i.e.

```
$url1= "http://www.example.com";
$final = "http://yourdomain.com?url1=".urlencode($url1);
```

Comment: looks like I badly formulated the question. After I click on generated url, I'll have `$_REQUEST['url1']` ... `$_REQUEST['urln']` on server. Do I have to do `urldecode($_REQUEST['url1'])` before `header("Location: $url")`

Comment: no.
Manual sais: "The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results." (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php )

Answer (score 3):

My proposal is to use:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php